# Streamed transfer + netTcpBinding = framing mode not supported?

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

Can anybody explain what this error means:

> The .Net Framing mode being used is
>   not supported by blah blah yadda

I can't find any info worthwhile.  The exception says to check the server logs, however I can't find anything in them relating to this error.  I don't know what the hell a "framing mode" is, otherwise I'd try different framing modes.

What I'm trying to do is to create a TCP WCF endpoint to send a Stream to the client.

---

Here's the interface (prototyping):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IXpsService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream GetCurrentDocument();
}
```

Comment: How does the interface look like?

Comment: Possibly relevant:  I'm combining the server and client in the same application.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One of the ways this error occurs is if there is a mismatch in the configuration of the client and the server.

The default is **buffered**, if one is set to **streaming**, when they try to talk to each other you get a framing error.

It thinks that each batch of data that the buffered tries to send over is a frame.

Comment: Yeah, that was it.  Problem was in the CreateChannel call; wasn't setting the transfer mode.