# WCF Streaming: Framing mode error in net.tcp only

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, stream, nettcpbinding

I have one application server implementing a bunch of services using default `transferMode="Buffered"` and one `Streamed` service. It exposes endpoints for `basicHttp` and `net.tcp` protocols, and runs in production under dozens of IIS 7.0+ configurations without incident.

When I went to replicate the architecture for a new application's server, streaming over net.tcp simply refused to work, throwing the perfectly opaque and obtuse `ProtocolException`

> The .Net Framing mode being used is not supported by *MyNetTcpEndpointAddress*. See the server logs for more details.

Yeah right, the "server logs". (There's nothing, whether traced or not.) Service architectures and web.configs for S1 and S2 are identical, except for

- some name changes
- a custom namespace in S2 (S1 using tempuri)
- different ports (S1 and S2 both using ports in the 8000-9000 range)

Streaming service S2 works just fine under `basicHttp`.

Having tried everything and failed to make the error go away, I built a test client that does nothing but run my service architecture with some `Ping` methods. No custom namespace, no frills, just the original configs, and lite services, contracts, and hand-coded wrappers around the `ChannelFactory` proxies.

Same error:

> The .Net Framing mode being used is not supported by 'net.tcp://localhost:9931/StreamingService.svc'. See the server logs for more details.

The buffered test service works under both protocols, and the streamed service works under `basicHttp`, as in S2.

All testing done on the same Win7 machine with a complete IIS setup. The test app is still too big to post here, but here are the complete configs, and the console code

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <!-- throttling of stream size is partially controlled by this setting -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" /><!-- 1GB -->
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="FooService.svc" service="WcfTest.Services.FooService" />
        <add relativeAddress="StreamingService.svc" service="WcfTest.Services.StreamingService" />
     </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="200000" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding
                 openTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" closeTimeout="00:20:00"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="12000" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="WcfTest.Streaming.Http" transferMode="Streamed"
                 openTimeout="03:00:00" sendTimeout="03:00:00" receiveTimeout="03:00:00" closeTimeout="03:00:00"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" /><!-- 1GB -->
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding
                 openTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" closeTimeout="00:20:00"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="12000" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="WcfTest.Streaming.Tcp" transferMode="Streamed"
                 openTimeout="03:00:00" sendTimeout="03:00:00" receiveTimeout="03:00:00" closeTimeout="03:00:00"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824"><!-- 1GB -->
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding" />
      <add scheme="net.tcp" binding="netTcpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfTest.Services.Streaming">
        <!-- http -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WcfTest.Streaming.Http" contract="WcfTest.Contracts.IStreamingService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <!-- net.tcp -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WcfTest.Streaming.Tcp" contract="WcfTest.Contracts.IStreamingService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**app.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="200000"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="customQuotaBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding
                 openTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" closeTimeout="00:20:00"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="12000" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="WcfTest.Bindings.Streaming.Http" transferMode="Streamed"
                 openTimeout="03:00:00" sendTimeout="03:00:00" receiveTimeout="03:00:00" closeTimeout="03:00:00"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824"><!-- 1GB -->
          </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding
                 openTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" closeTimeout="00:20:00"
                 maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="12000" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="WcfTest.Bindings.Streaming.Tcp" transferMode="Streamed"
                 openTimeout="03:00:00" sendTimeout="03:00:00" receiveTimeout="03:00:00" closeTimeout="03:00:00"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824"><!-- 1GB -->
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <!-- Foo -->
      <endpoint name="WcfTest.Endpoints.Foo.Http" address="http://localhost:9930/FooService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfTest.Contracts.IFooService" />
      <endpoint name="WcfTest.Endpoints.Foo.Tcp" address="net.tcp://localhost:9931/FooService.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WcfTest.Contracts.IFooService" />

      <!-- Streaming -->
      <endpoint name="WcfTest.Endpoints.Streaming.Http" address="http://localhost:9930/StreamingService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WcfTest.Bindings.Streaming.Http" contract="WcfTest.Contracts.IStreamingService" />
      <endpoint name="WcfTest.Endpoints.Streaming.Tcp" address="net.tcp://localhost:9931/StreamingService.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WcfTest.Bindings.Streaming.Tcp" contract="WcfTest.Contracts.IStreamingService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**console test call**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("starting WcfTest client...");

            Console.WriteLine();
            PingFoo(Contracts.Enums.Protocol.Http);
            PingFoo(Contracts.Enums.Protocol.Tcp);

            Console.WriteLine();
            PingStreaming(Contracts.Enums.Protocol.Http);
            // only this call errors:
            PingStreaming(Contracts.Enums.Protocol.Tcp);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("ENTER to exit WcfTest client...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static bool PingFoo(Contracts.Enums.Protocol protocol)
        {
            FooProxy pxy = new FooProxy(protocol);
            return PingProxy<IFooService>(pxy, protocol);
        }

        private static bool PingStreaming(Contracts.Enums.Protocol protocol)
        {
            StreamingProxy pxy = new StreamingProxy(protocol);
            return PingProxy<IStreamingService>(pxy, protocol);
        }

        private static bool PingProxy<T>(ProxyServiceBase<T> pxy, Contracts.Enums.Protocol protocol) where T : IServiceBase
        {
            bool success = pxy.Ping(); 
            Console.WriteLine("ping {0} {1}: {2}", pxy.GetType().Name, protocol, success ? " success" : " FAILED");
            if (pxy != null)
                pxy.Close();
            return success;
        }
```

Any ideas why this would be failing on one IIS site, under one of two protocols, and not on another? (It is not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466221/streamed-transfer-nettcpbinding-framing-mode-not-supported).)

**EDIT:** In preparation for taking this bounty-side, a couple clarifications on this test service and client:

First, per commenter's suggestion, svcutil works fine against http, but fails against net.tcp. Here is the complete output of that run:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>svcutil
>   net.tcp://localhost:9931/StreamingService.svc Microsoft (R) Service
>   Model Metadata Tool [Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication
>   Foundation, Version 3.0.4506.2152] Copyright (c) Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Attempting to download metadata from
>   'net.tcp://localhost:9931/StreamingService.svc' using WS-Metadata
>   Exchange. This UR L does not support DISCO. Microsoft (R) Service
>   Model Metadata Tool [Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication
>   Foundation, Version 3.0.4506.2152] Copyright (c) Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   net.tcp://localhost:9931/StreamingService.svc
>
> If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you
>   have access, please check that you have enabled m etadata publishing
>   at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing,
>   please refer to the MSDN documentat ion at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.
>
> WS-Metadata Exchange Error
>   URI: net.tcp://localhost:9931/StreamingService.svc
>
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:9931/StreamingService.svc'.
>
> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout bei ng exceeded by
>   the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:04:59.9929993'.
>
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> If you would like more help, type "svcutil /?"

Second, removing `"transferMode="Streamed"` from the `Wcf.Bindings.Streaming.Tcp` web and app configs pasted above allows the service to ping just fine. It does not improve the svcutil situation.

Finally, here are some other things I have tried, with no improvement:

- Various versions of `serviceMetadata` attribute in `serviceBehaviors` (which I understand to be overridden by the existence of `mex` endpoints anyway)
- Various named `serviceBehaviors` instead of the default I include
- Various configurations of `security mode=` on the binding, especially `None`
- Various disablings of all other bindings, endpoints, etc. in hopes that one thing might be getting in another's way

Comment: Put code of `StreamingProxy` for inspect.

Comment: @Jones There's nothing in that proxy. The channel-opening and `Ping` call happen in the `ProxyServiceBase`, which as I said is identical to the earlier service that is working

Comment: Using `svcutil net.tcp://localhost:9931/StreamingService.svc` and verify is response correct. If not problem using log http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.100).aspx for detection point of the error is occur exactly

Comment: @Jones Sorry to be so slow responding... I get "Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved" response from svcutil. Did a lot of searching on that, but my metadata configurations are fine (and, importantly, the same as they were on the previous/comparison service). Enabled tracing and there is no error in the log.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that transferMode of tcp communication either at service side or client side to Streamed and the other side still uses the default mode which is Buffered.

Are you forgetting something in "StreamingProxy" in case of TCP?

May be this will help...
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/37e32166-63f3-4cb9-ab81-14caa50cd91e/help-with-error-message-the-net-framing-mode-being-used-is-not-supported-by-?forum=wcf

Also I am trying looking further for your solution...

Comment: Client (app) and server (web) config files are in the original post, both clearly stated as using Streamed. I don't know what "Are you forgetting something in "StreamingProxy" in case of TCP?" means, since I am not setting my protocols in code.

Comment: I mean to say that did you set  
binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed in StreamingProxy class of ping method even if you set it in app.config? (As jones also stated for code).
Trying to figuring out if wcf is configured properly then it should be client that using buffered mode as both config seems ok.